# Why would you use two pages in a row for a website address?

Tags: html, url, web

This is just a curiosity. I've seen this couple times:

```
http://www.website.com/index.php/en/contacts.html
```

What is a reasoning behind this logic? Why do we have php file followed by html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people find it easier to have a single `index.php` file that includes (among other things) things like connecting to the database, the basic layout of the page (navigation, footer, etc.) and suchlike, then have it include the actual file (in this case `/en/contacts.html`) inside it.

Personally, I think this is a bad idea because there are so many better ways to do this. One of them being the `auto_prepend_file` and `auto_append_file` options in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to tell for sure, but I'd bet on the "en/contacts.html" being the path to the file for index.php to include (super bad practice). Do not use this syntax of URLs, as they aren't user nor search-engine friendly.

Comment: they're search engine friendly, but unless you protect them, you can let users load things like: `http://www.website.com/index.php/en/../../../etc/passwd` or something....

Comment: @tkone Google prefers user-readable URLs, index.php/en/contacts.html is definitely not the best option for that.

Comment: Google has no idea what the URL is -- so long as the routing is being done by javascript (a la twitter's hash-bang URL scenario), Google can index any URL and return the correct page.  And that's much better than something like `http://www.website.com/story/0,0,111,103,234.html` thankyouverymuchvinettestoryserver

Comment: @tkone Google uses URL to rate the page content and context so the URL should always reflect the page content and be as human-readable as possible, not be some cryptic BS. In addition to that it's just good practice

Comment: Yes but that URL is descriptive, even to a computer. It's the English version of a contact page. That url is bad for many reasons but not really due to seo.

Comment: http://www.website.com/en/contacts.html is a good url for SEO, including irrelevant stuff is always harmful (even if it's short, it's still irrelevant).

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely using a framework that includes some routing mechanism. The index.php takes in /en/contacts.html as a parameter, retrieves the appropriate file(s) and processes them based on pre-determined rules.

In most cases a rewrite rule is used in Apache or Nginx (or whatever webserver is being used) so the url can be in the form:

```
http://www.website.com/en/contacts.html
```

Then everything following the root is interpreted as a parameter in index.php.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP (And I believe other server side language), you can get the path after `index.php` by referring to the superglobal `$_SERVER['path_info']` in this case the value is

`/en/contacts.html`

, you can then process the path in your application as however you see fit (for instance in MVC, `/users/list`, you'd initialize `users` controller and run `list` action on it)